# Matlab GUI changes 2009a->2011b?

Tags: user-interface, matlab

I have a skeleton GUI application which puts up a simple set of menus whose entries share a common callback function whose only effect is to set the value of a global variable, MenuItem, which is different for each entry. Different functions are then called for each value of MenuItem inside a Switch-Case expression, the Switch-Case is held inside a While loop whose exit condition is for MenuItem to attain a certain value. In the tail of the While loop is a uiwait call, after the Switch-Case.

This worked fine under Matlab 2009a but since I upgraded to Matlab 2011b it is broken.

Under Matlab 2011b the value of MenuItem is changed in the callback but this changed value does not seem to propagate into the Switch-Case.

Any ideas of changes between 2009a and 2011b which might have caused this, and workarounds for them? I tried reading the release notes but couldn't spot anything which appeared relevant.

(I appreciate this is a slightly unorthodox way of structuring a GUI, it is born out of a background in commandline programming)

Comment: Please post your code, it is very hard to reproduce it. Or at least the error message.

Comment: MatLab has a debugger.  Use it.  Also, it sounds like you should be looking for changes in how global variables are handled, not GUI changes.

Comment: Will post code in the morning (GMT)

Comment: In constructing the minimal code which exhibited the error, I discovered my problem - I'd added a javaclasspath statement to do something (I thought) unrelated. If I comment it out then the code works again (except for the bit requiring the added java class). Thanks for the encouragement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the GUI API has changed in MATLAB between 2009a and 2011b. If the MenuItem changes do not propagate into the `switch` cases, then you should check that the `case` statements that you compare against are still valid.  You should at least post your code around the `switch` statement in order to make a more reasonable diagnosis.